# Add animation to an interactive map (javascript)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rvm

Hello  i got a problem for add animation to an interactive map.

I add a map in wordpress with the plugin responsive vector map... at the moment it works, but i need to add animation to the interactive map, in special, regions of the map that appear separated and then come together forming the map.

I've been searching, but I haven't found any solution.

Thank you for your attention and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps API and code it by hand if you are good at coding :)